# Creating a private Discord Channel using Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a discord bot, that when you type >contract, it creates a new private channel & adds the message author, and the Admin role into the new channel. I have this code so far, but when trying to run the command, the bot does nothing. Not sure where my problem is coming from, if someone could take a look and share some insight? tia

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

Token = '..'

client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged on as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def contract(ctx, *, name=None):
  if ctx.author == client.user:
    return
    guild = ctx.guild
    member = ctx.author
    admin_role = get(guild.roles, name="Admin")
    overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}
  if name == None:
    await ctx.channel.send('Sorry, but you have to insert a name. Try again, but do it like this: `>contract [channel name]`')
  else:
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name, overwrites=overwrites)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Created a channel named {name}")

client.run(Token)
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real access token. If it is, please change it immediately now that you've published it to the internet.

Comment: It's just a testing bot, in a dead server. I've edited though, thanks

Comment: It's still in the edit history. You should revoke the token.

Comment: Yeah, the token is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at your indentation.

The code in `contract` is mostly inside the `if ctx.author == client.user: return` block, and as you should know, no code after `return` is executed. (Good IDEs and editors warn you about unreachable code.)

You might have a better time with something like this – handle exceptional cases and errors first and do the real work at the end of your function.

```
@bot.command()
async def contract(ctx, *, name=None):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return
    if not name:
        await ctx.channel.send(
            "Sorry, but you have to insert a name. "
            "Try again, but do it like this: `>contract [channel name]`"
        )
        return
    guild = ctx.guild
    member = ctx.author
    admin_role = get(guild.roles, name="Admin")
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    }
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name, overwrites=overwrites)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Created a channel named {name}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on handling errors, and exceptional cases first. I've tried your code, and my bot still isn't executing anything when trying the command.

Comment: If there is no error message either, then you'll need to e.g. add print commands (or use a debugger) to figure out where it's executing and where it's not executing.

Comment: I've tried debugging, and adding in print commands but still unsure where my problem is - I've tried adding in simple commands like ```@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.channel.send(arg)``` but my bot is still unresponsive. It has all of the relevant permissions.

Comment: AKX, I got it working. Turns out it didn't like me creating a client; `discord.client`, and a bot.